# flattern a dictionary and change key names

Tags: python, dictionary

how shoud i solve this ?
i have a dictionary like this

i wanna flattern this and If a key is already present in the result dict, add a suffix like "_1" to distinguish between keys with the same name.

```py
student_da = {
    'id1': {
        'name': 'mike',
        'age': 28,
        'salary': 2000
    },
    'id2': {
        'name': 'Sara',
        'age': 18,
        'salary': 1000
    },
    "a": "A",
    'id3': {
         'name': 'Omid',
         "age": 20,
         'salary': 1000
    },
    'id4': dict(name="Amir", age=28, salary=2000),
    "last_name": "messi",
}
```

output:

```py
{name_0: mike, age_0: 28, salary_0: 2000, ..., a: A, ...,  name_1: sara, ..., last_name: messi}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a [questions and answers
site](https://stackoverflow.com/about), not a code-writing service. Please read
through [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your
question to reflect your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since datasource is not clean. So the process will not straightforward. Not sure do you need output like this?

```py
records = {'id1': {'name': 'mike', 'age': 28, 'salary': 2000 }, 'id2': {'name': 'Sara', 'age': 18, 'salary': 1000 }, "a": "A", 'id3': {'name': 'Omid', "age": 20, 'salary': 1000 }, 'id4': dict(name="Amir", age=28, salary=2000), "last_name": "messi", }
new_records = {}
n = 0

for r in records:
    if isinstance(records[r],dict):
        new_records[f"name_{n}"] = records[r]["name"]
        new_records[f"age_{n}"] = records[r]["age"]
        new_records[f"salary_{n}"] = records[r]["salary"]
        n += 1
    else:
        new_records.update({r: records[r]})

print(new_records)
```

```
print(new_records)
# {
'name_0': 'mike', 'age_0': 28, 'salary_0': 2000, 
'name_1': 'Sara', 'age_1': 18, 'salary_1': 1000, 
'a': 'A', 
'name_2': 'Omid', 'age_2': 20, 'salary_2': 1000, 
'name_3': 'Amir', 'age_3': 28, 'salary_3': 2000, 
'last_name': 'messi'
}
```

Comment: is there any way to code without class comand ?